# Spfx Site Designs - IsDefault behaviour has changed

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, site-design, site-script

When site designs were first launched, I swear that using the IsDefault parameter only added the site design to the default SharePoint site templates.

Now it appears that IsDefault both modifies the default templates, and adds the design to the drop down.

I preferred the original behaviour; is there any way to configure an IsDefault site design to not show up in the design selection UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it has been fixed. The IsDefault flag does not cause the site design to show up in the UI any more.